find a high pivot between two low pivots and viceversa
in this pinescript code I identify the high and low pivots but the problem is that sometimes they repeat (2 high pivots or more in a row and vice versa), in the code I can identify when they repeat, but I would like that when it identifies it, it finds a high pivot between 2 low pivots and vice versa (1 low pivot between two high pivots), with the code I also identified how many candles are apart from the ph or pl that repeat, but I can't find the ph between pl and the pl between ph, this is the code
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © pach22

//@version=5
indicator("Il mio script", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)
                                                               
leftBars = input.int(title = "left bars", defval = 15, minval = 1)
rightBars = input.int(title = "right bars", defval = 15, minval = 1)


//PH = PIVOT high

pivotHigh = ta.pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
pivotLow = ta.pivotlow(low, leftBars, rightBars)
var float lastPivotHighPrice = na
var float lastPivotLowPrice = na
var int lastPivotIndexHigh = na
var int lastPivotIndexLow = na
var string lastPivotType = ""

var float altezzaMax = na
var int altezzaMaxIndex = na
var int diff = na



if na(pivotLow) == false
    if lastPivotType == "low"
        label.new(bar_index[rightBars], pivotLow, text = "PL\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotLowPrice) + "\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotIndexLow) + "\nPl Ripetuto", style = label.style_label_up, color = #802424, textcolor = color.white, size = size.small)       
        diff := bar_index - lastPivotIndexLow
        label.new(bar_index[rightBars], pivotLow, text = str.tostring(diff), style = label.style_label_up, size = size.huge)

        for i = bar_index to lastPivotIndexLow
            if high[i] > high[lastPivotIndexLow[1]]
                altezzaMax := high[i]
                //altezzaMaxIndex := bar_index[i]
        
        if na(altezzaMax) == false
            label.new(bar_index ,high, text = "high" + str.tostring(altezzaMax))

    else
        label.new(bar_index[rightBars], pivotLow, text = "PL\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotLowPrice) + "\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotIndexLow), style = label.style_label_up, color = color.red, textcolor = color.white)

    lastPivotIndexLow := bar_index
    lastPivotLowPrice := close
    lastPivotType := "low"
    

if na(pivotHigh) == false
    if lastPivotType == "high"
        label.new(bar_index[rightBars], pivotHigh, text = "PH\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotHighPrice)+ "\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotIndexHigh) + "\nPh Ripetuto", style = label.style_label_down, color = color.rgb(21, 82, 23), textcolor = color.white, size = size.small)

    else
        label.new(bar_index[rightBars], pivotHigh, text = "PH\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotHighPrice)+ "\n" + str.tostring(lastPivotIndexHigh), style = label.style_label_down, color = color.green, textcolor = color.white)

    lastPivotIndexHigh := bar_index
    lastPivotHighPrice := close
    lastPivotType := "high"



I expected that with the for loop to find the high pivot among the low pivots it would find it for me but in reality it identifies another candle that has nothing to do with it

Try ta.pivot_point_levels
